# How do I connect Django from desktop to the remote Mysql Server?

Tags: mysql, django

I want to use Django to control the backend of my website from my desktop, so I configured a no-ip host, and added it to the remote MySql section, but I can't connect the MySql server.

I tried to change the default database hostname from localhost to the no-ip host but I can't find option to do it.

How do I do this?

Comment: is mysql running? can you connect to mysql independent of django. example `mysql -u yourusername -p -h the host?? If you cannot connect to it normally it is not a django problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `DATABASES` setting in your `settings.py`. You should have something like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Just change `localhost` to your desired hostname.